# Does the following mean my SSD is about to fail?

Tags: linux, ssd, arch-linux, hard-drive-failure, manjaro

```
    [iceguru@stuxnet ~]$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda
smartctl 6.3 2014-07-26 r3976 [x86_64-linux-3.14.21-1-MANJARO] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-14, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Intel 520 Series SSDs
Device Model:     INTEL SSDSC2CW120A3
Serial Number:    CVCV203503C7120BGN
LU WWN Device Id: 5 001517 bb2812260
Firmware Version: 400i
User Capacity:    120,034,123,776 bytes [120 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2 T13/2015-D revision 3
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sat Oct 18 12:02:07 2014 CDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        ( 2097) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7f) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Abort Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  48) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x0021) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours_and_Msec 0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       895808h+42m+44.030s
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       72
170 Available_Reservd_Space 0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
171 Program_Fail_Count      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
172 Erase_Fail_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
174 Unexpect_Power_Loss_Ct  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       63
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0033   100   100   090    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
187 Uncorrectable_Error_Cnt 0x000f   120   120   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       63
225 Host_Writes_32MiB       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       15323
226 Workld_Media_Wear_Indic 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       65535
227 Workld_Host_Reads_Perc  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       37
228 Workload_Minutes        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       65535
232 Available_Reservd_Space 0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
233 Media_Wearout_Indicator 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
241 Host_Writes_32MiB       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       15323
242 Host_Reads_32MiB        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       9317
249 NAND_Writes_1GiB        0x0013   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       564

SMART Error Log not supported

SMART Self-test Log not supported

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 0
Note: revision number not 1 implies that no selective self-test has ever been run
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing in the SMART data you posted to indicate that the drive is anywhere near failure.

Let's go through this report in more detail. Here is the first indication that SMART has found no critical, "data-loss-is-imminent" types of problems:

```
=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
```

If the SMART considered failure imminent, the overall-health self-assessment test result would not be `PASSED`, but something more ominous.

Skipping down to the SMART Attributes table, note the absence of anything in the WHEN_FAILED column. That means that none of the attribute values has now (or ever) been found to beyond their healthy thresholds. If any values are (or had) passed a critical threshold, you would see something like `FAILING_NOW` or `IN_THE_PAST` there, instead of the null values (represented by hyphens).

Having said all of that, you should not necessarily take a healthy-looking SMART report as 100% proof that the drive is not about to fail. Drives of any type can suddenly fail at any time, long before any indication of problems appear in the SMART attributes. In other words, take a good SMART attribute report as *evidence* of a healthy drive, not as absolute *proof* of it. If your data must not be lost, you must have a good backup strategy.

Comment: I get block errors when starting up and shutting down. Hence my worry.